# ¿Existe alguna forma de agregar nuevos input segun la cantidad que el usuario elija en el formulario de React Native?

Tags: react-native, reactjs, programación-móvil

me veo en la urgencia de preguntar esto

Necesito generar preguntar al usuario ¿Cuantas asistentes están presentes en la estacion de servicio? y que luego que escriba la cantidad, se generen debajo nuevos .

En Desarrollo Web se hace sin problemas, usano el append de jQuery por ejemplo. Pero en React Native no he conseguido generarlos